# formatted_profile_url NOT working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url

I am updating a rails 2.2.2 app to 3.0.3.While updating i got an error like this

`` undefined method `formatted_profile_url' for #<#:0xa4f2cac> ``

And the line which generate error is 


`<%= auto_discovery_link_tag :rss, formatted_profile_url(@profile, :rss), :title=>"#{@profile.f}'s recent activity" %>

<%= auto_discovery_link_tag :rss, formatted_profile_blogs_url(@profile, :rss), :title=>"#{@profile.f}'s Blogs" %>

<%= auto_discovery_link_tag :rss, formatted_profile_photos_url(@profile, :rss), :title=>"#{@profile.f}'s Photos" %><% end -%>`

Is this formatted_Xx_x is a deprecated method? pls help

Comment: Do you corrected your `config/routes.rb` file?

Comment: No..thats not the issue.. I got ans
its here... http://bit.ly/f338k4

Comment: Thats a rails function which deprecated.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. That function is deprecated and the [solution is here](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/11/27/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-no-more-formatted-routes).